# Compare two tables in MS Access SQL query

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access

I have two Excel tables (A and B) with names of staff. I want to compare these two tables in MS Access.

I have an Access query which compares a field like *[Lastname, Firstname]* and gave me as result for every member of *Table A* with no equivalent member in *Table B*. In my SQL query, Access made a simple string compare. For example:

```
SELECT User.A, User.B 
WHERE User.A Is Null
```

The problem is that the name with umlauten (ä,ü,ö,ß) are not written synchron in both tables. Sometimes I have ä or ae, ü or ue etc. Can I use regex in Access SQL to solve this problem?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Also, please post full, actual, attempted SQL query. Posted example is not compilable and does no *simple string compare*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would take is to translate the names into a standardized format, in a derived column in both table A and B.  Then you can use this column for a simple string comparison.

The translation can be accomplished using the [`replace`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Replace-Function-6acf209b-01b7-4078-b4b8-e0a4ef67d181) function in Access.